# Mysql - copy part of a string to another field and delete the string

Tags: mysql, replace

In Mysql in one of my fields I have for example this string -

> some text [= ajunkt]

I want to copy part of the string inside the square brackets, precisely

> ajunkt

to another field and delete [= ajunkt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is same you can use `substring_index` to get that part of the string as

```
mysql> select substring_index(substring_index('some text [= ajunkt]','[=',-1),']',1) as copy;
+---------+
| copy    |
+---------+
|  ajunkt |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now to copy the text in another filed you can use as

```
update table_name
set 
copy_col_name = substring_index(substring_index(col_name','[=',-1),']',1);
```

Finally you can replace that part from the existing string as

```
 select 
 replace(
   'some text [= ajunkt]',
   concat(
     '[= ',
     trim(
       substring_index(
         substring_index('some text [= ajunkt]',
         '[=',-1),
        ']',1
        ) 
      ),
    ']'
  ),
'') as new_str ;


+------------+
| new_str    |
+------------+
| some text  |
+------------+
```

change the select in the above as update and replace the hard-coded input value as column name.